# How do I increase the width of paragraphs?

Tags: spacing

I need to increase the room in the information sections of each entry, so that the margin on the right side of the page is not so large. For example, the first employment experience entry is Lehman Brothers and the author put some information about what he did at the company. I'd like to increase the horizontal space those entries take up, all throughout the document so that there isn't so much empty space on the right side of the page.

I'm assuming the code is somewhere in the pre-amble of the document, which is this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here
```

I'm using this template: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-styled-cv

What must I edit or add to make the right margin smaller, and have the text in every entry fill up the space that's been taken from the margin? I hope my question makes sense. Essentially, I need to make all the paragraphs in the document wider.

Comment: Quicker and more comprehensive answers are usually gained when the OP posts a complete, but [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) rather than code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a workaround for you, but first.

1) Templates built by someone else are always problematic.

2) When you make a change in a template, there are often unexpected, surprising, and often ugly results.

3) Personally, I would recommend that you build your own resume document using the memoir class, which has excellent documentation.

Now for this specific problem do the following.

Put this line immediately before the `\begin{document}` line

```
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

You can adjust the four margins to your specific requirements.

The results are as follows:

[image]

Comment: Why do you suggest making your own resume class if edits to a template will suffice? In any case, I appreciate the suggestion and have accepted your answer.

Comment: @user81575 Primarily if in the future you have to make a major change to the format of the resume, it may not be possible to even modify someone else's template.   This specific template is built on a combination of a curriculum vita style and a classic thesis style.   The thesis style has most of it styling tightly coded internal and would be difficult to modify.   Glad that this will work and I recommend you hang around this board and learn the capabilities of LaTeX.  Also, pick a user name which you would be willing to have associated with you for a long and  successful career.

Comment: Much appreciation for the guidance. Do you have any suggestions for getting to know LaTeX aside from this stack exchange?

Comment: Here is a great Q&A with options for learning both free and not free.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner The best way to learn is to use LaTeX and when you have a question first try in the resources to find the answer.  If that fails then ask a questions here.  Be sure and read the discussion on MWE before your next question.  Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What is MWE? Minimum working example?

Comment: @user81575  That's correct.  [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Classicthesis uses areaset, might be better to change the text width by increasing the default width of 336pt by

```
\areaset[current]{336pt}{750pt} 
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}
```

after the call to classicthesis package.